# Flutter InkWell Hover Function

Tags: flutter

Trying to enlarge my picture(clipped with ClipPath) using InkWell function(onHover) but when i hover picture nothing happens.

```
InkWell(
                        onTap: () {},
                        onHover: (isHovering) {
                          if (isHovering) {
                            setState(() {
                              sizeBool = !sizeBool;
                            });
                          }
                        },
                        child: ClipPath(
                          child: AnimatedContainer(
                            duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            height: sizeBool ? 450 : 150,
                            child: Image.network(
                              'image.url',
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                          ),
                          clipper: CustomClipPath(),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the parents of the InkWell?

Comment: check my answer you can get hover effect using this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63780118/5370550

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this: [dartpad link](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/261e87e6608478ea9bc307b154d66ebb)

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  double sideLength = 50;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedContainer(
      height: sideLength,
      width: sideLength,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      curve: Curves.easeIn,
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        child: InkWell(
          onTap:(){},
            onHover: (value) {
              print(value);
            setState(() {
              sideLength = value?150 :50;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: not working. you think is it about clipper ?, not printing the value btw

Comment: nope just removed clipPath, code same as yours, not working

Comment: I put my cod in dartpad and it working, [Link](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/261e87e6608478ea9bc307b154d66ebb)

Comment: can I see all you widget?

Comment: i tested my own widget in dartpad, mine is working too on dartpad, but not working with emulator...

Comment: maybe it's not working with emulator because you can't hover with phone , i mean you have to touch screen to do something logically ?

Answer (score 21):

Define `onTap()` with `onHover()`. It will work:

```
InkWell(
onTap: (){},
onHover: (val) {
setState(() {isHover = val;
      });
  },
),
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to wrap InkWell with "Material" widget with color: Colors.transparent

```
Material(
  color: Colors.transparent,
  child: InkWell(
    ...
  )
)
```

Comment: didnt print onHover: (val) { print('hover'); } ,, this doesnt work ...